# Can I connect a POTS cable over a CAT6a cable?

Tags: networking, router, cable

I currently have a UK Master socket which splits into 2 circuits 4 wire for phone extensions and AB line for RJ11 ADSL2 modems.

I can run POTS extensions from the socket, but I need to extend the AB line too. Can I place a CAT6a shielded pairs cable with sockets by the master socket and jumper the AB line? So I can connect a modem at the other end and would only be using 2 wires currently but will have the extension ready for FTTN.

Comment: Just to be clear. BT places the Master socket wherever it is convenient for their cables coming from outside and they control the location as they are responsible for those cables and I am unable to move the Master socket from it's location near the front door. I need to place extensions to move the modem upstairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, Cat 5, 6 or 7 Ethernet cable can handle up to four POTS phone lines, or any other service (e.g., switching) using twisted pairs In fact, there are are [RJ11 (POTS) to RJ45 (Ethernet) adapters](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=rj11%20to%20rj45). The simplest choice might be:

- Install Cat 6a or other Ethernet cable using standard RJ45 wall jacks.
- Clearly *label* all jacks for POTS., not Ethernet, and perhaps list the chosen colors for each line (extra info might be put on a file-card and tucked behind the  jack).
- Buy or make a splitter cable, [RJ45](https://networkencyclopedia.com/rj-connectors/) to up to four single phone line RJ11 jacks, or connect up to three of the Ethernet twisted pairs to one RJ11 connector for multi-line phones -- the other twisted pair could be used for signalling or low power applications. For phone systems using digital data service (DDS), the [RJ48](https://networkencyclopedia.com/rj-connectors/) connection scheme could be used. Again, put cable tags to clearly label the separate phone lines.

Comment: POTS over cat 5 used to be 'standard' in new builds here before they realised/switched to just setting them up as ethernet. There was also a lot of small network contractors who'd switch your lines from POTS to ethernet too